# how to select html tags in .css file .?

Tags: html, css

I am having `class` and `value` for every `tag` then .css is selecting them.

**Code**

```html
<ul class="heading">
  <li value="navbar"><a value="link" href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li value="navbar"><a value="link" href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li value="navbar"><a value="link" href="more.html">MORE</a></li>
</ul>
```

when I try to select element like , `.li{}` , in `css` file the `tags` does not apply on it.

Here is the `image of css file` [this the image of css file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNpkF.png) and [this the image of html tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfBcG.png). Please help me get out of this problem.

Comment: Post your code here not as image, read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: What does the browser object inspector show when you select an element?

Comment: Now the question is not clear at all (((

Comment: `code`<body>
         <ul class="heading">
            <li value="navbar"><a value="link" href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li value="navbar"><a value="link" href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li value="navbar"><a value="link" href="more.html">MORE</a></li>
        </ul> `code` this is the html code i am putting value and class in every tag but i want to select html  tags in css file without values @sfili_81 ,@sergey kuznetsov @

Answer (score 2):

You can not select li that way. You should select it this way

```
li{
 /// rest of the code
}
```

More about [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: without (.) period ?? @user9877945

Comment: @dank_coder, `.` is needed when you have a class , element selector does not need `.`

Answer (score -1):

just put like below:

```
li{
//your styles goes here
}
```

Comment: hey can you please review my both screen shots. please check them and improve my mistake. thanks @Asutosh

Comment: if I understand ".li{} , in css file the tags dose not apply on it", it wont get appliied because you dont have any css clas in HTML as li. To select all list items you can select as I have given in the answer.

Comment: thank you i will try this.  but how should i add css class in html? @Asutosh

Comment: No need to add css class if you are doing this.

Comment: @dank_coder can you please mark this as answer then, it will be helpful for others.